# Changing the content of a text area with grease monkey

Tags: javascript

Here is the script i used :

```
var textarea = document.getElementsById("commentBodyField");
textarea.value = "Hello";
```

When i activate greasemonkey and refresh the page, nothing changes in the text area.
I got the text area id (commentBodyField)with the browser Inspect Element function

Answer (score 0):

The function is called `getElementById`, not Element**s**.

Comment: @user3383133: Did you check if the script does run at all? e.g. by running an `alert()` or `console.log()`. You might also want to check _when_ the script is run by greasemonkey.

Comment: yes, the alert works, so my question is, is there some sort of protection on web pages that prevent such scripts from working? (anti spam bots for exemple)